# Python script to export the all subfolders in a folder into separate .ZIP folders, but ignoring individual files?

Tags: python, zip, compression, subdirectory, archive

I have a directory of subfolders that gets populated with another script. Each of those subfolders in the directory need to be compressed into a .ZIP folder.

However in that directory is also a number of files (PDFs, .TXTs etc) that are not in subfolders. I'm trying to create a script that will create zip folders out of the individual sub folders, but totally ignore the individual files.

```
import os
import zipfile

path = r"E:\Test\XYZ L48"
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(path)))
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('{0}.zip'.format(os.path.join(path, folder)), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.wal k(os.path.join(path, folder)):
        for filename in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)), arcname=filename)
    zipf.close()
```

I tried this, which worked to create ZIPs out the subfolders, but also archives all the files.

Is there a way to modify this to ignore files in the directory, and only zip the sub folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of `listdir`. Then you can check to see if each is a file, a directory, or a symbolic link.